# Problemas cuando capturo parámetros de la url usando php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc, controller

Tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo.

Estoy haciendo el controlador de una función para listar unos productos.

La función del modelo me funciona perfectamente:

```
function list_item_by_id($id){
  global $link;

  $id = (int)$id;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM items
          INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias_id = categorias.id
          WHERE items.id = $id";

  $query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

  if( $num_rows > 0 ){
    return $query;
  }

  return false;
}
```

En cuanto al controlador me da error porque no consigo que me coja la id del item. Me sale el error `i101`.

Explico lo que hago. Creo un array con los diferentes tipos de ids que me pueden llegar por GET, capturo el tipo de id que obtengo por GET y la almaceno en una variable. Luego compruebo si esa id existe en el array, y en caso afirmativo lo saneo.

Hasta aquí todo bien (o eso creo). Haciendo var_dump() me va devolviendo los resultados que quiero.
El problema lo tengo cuando pregunto si no hay $id, no entiendo por que me salta si por GET le estoy pasando `?pid=30`

```
function list_item_by_id_controller(){
    global $link, $gf_query;

    $id_types = array('eid','hid','pid','poid','bid');

    foreach( $_GET as $key => $value ){
        $array_key[] = $key;
    }

    foreach ( $array_key as $k ){
        if( in_array($k, $id_types) ){
            $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $id_types);
        }
    }

    if(!$id){
        $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i101';
            return false;
    }

    $query = list_item_by_id($id);

    if( !$query ){
        $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i102';
        return false;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Si ejecuto la función `list_item_by_id_controller()` este es el resultado en pantalla `array(1) { ["message_code"]=> string(4) "i101" }`

Alguien ve algún error en el código que no soy capaz de detectar?

Gracias

Comment: Realmente no entiendo cuál es la utilidad de `filter_input`. Si vas a usar ese dato en una consulta lo mejor es usar consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **RESPUESTA EDITADA**: Ver comentarios en el código.

Aunque la función del modelo te *funcione perfectamente* me voy a permitir criticarle dos aspectos que me parecen importantes:

1. Veo que usas: `global $link;` El uso de globales es considerado por lo general una mala práctica. Por varios motivos. Si por ejemplo en una ejecución anterior *alguien* escribe: `$link=null`. No podrás controlar ese cambio que hará que la conexión sea nula. **Solución:** Usar una clase que maneje las conexiones e instanciarla con `new` cada vez que la vayas a usar.
2. Si quieres proteger la consulta enviada a la base de datos, `filter_input` no es la mejor opción. Es mucho más seguro y fácil usar consultas preparadas.

Si te decides por ello, habría que hacer cambios en tu función:

```
function list_item_by_id($id){
    global $link;  /* Aunque funcione, no es una buena práctica */

    $id = (int)$id;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items
              INNER JOIN categorias ON categorias_id = categorias.id
              WHERE items.id = ?";

    /* crear una sentencia preparada */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$sql)) {

        /* 
         *ligar parámetros para marcadores 
         *He asumido que id es entero en la bd, si es varchar
         *cambias la siguiente línea por:
         * mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);;
         */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

        /* ejecutar la consulta */
        $stmt->execute();
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

     /* Guardar el resultado */
       $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

       $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


          if( $num_rows > 0 ){
            return $result;
          }

          return false;
        } else {

            /* Aquí manejar posible fallo de consulta */

        }
    }
```

Luego, no tienes que sanear nada:

```
function list_item_by_id_controller(){
    global $link, $gf_query; /* Las globales, ohh no. */

    $id_types = array('eid','hid','pid','poid','bid');

    /* Obtenemos las llaves del GET */
    $getKeys = array_keys($_GET);

    foreach ( $getKeys as $k ){
        if( in_array($k, $id_types) ){
            /* 
             * Puedes guardar id tal cual
             * La consulta preparada se encarga de sanear los valores
            */
            $id = $_GET[$k]; /* filter_input(INPUT_GET, $id_types); */
        }
    }

    if(!$id){
        $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i101';
            return false;
    }

    $query = list_item_by_id($id);

    if( !$query ){
        $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i102';
        return false;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Cedano. Estoy comenzando con PHP y aún me cuesta POO. Estoy haciendo las cosas según nos enseñan en el Máster que estoy estudiando ;D

Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: O sea, ¿tienes que ceñirte al estilo procedural? Dentro de un momento modificaré el código para adaptarlo a ese estilo y haré una prueba con datos reales. Por rapidez no me di cuenta que no estás posteando nada con `id`, por lo que esto `$id = $_GET["id"];` no funcionará... Cuando tenga un momento disponible modificaré la respuesta.

Comment: He editado la respuesta @SilviaPena usando el estilo por procedimientos. También muestro una forma más fácil de comparar los parámetros de `$_GET` con el array de parámetros posibles.

Comment: @Cedano he estado comprobando tu corrección, pero sigue sin funcionar. Me lanza el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function list_item_by_id(). Es decir, no puede leer $query: $query = list_item_by_id($id);

Comment: @SilviaPena el error: ***Call to undefined function list_item_by_id*** parecería indicar que por error le cambiaste el nombre a la función, no es problema del código en sí, lo que dice el error es que la función `list_item_by_id` no existe. ¿Podrías verificar que no le cambiaste el nombre o que está en el contexto desde donde la llamas?

Comment: @Cedano ya he solucionado el tema de la función. Estaba tan preocupada con el código de la función, pensando que el error estaba ahí, que no me dí cuenta y no cargué el archivo ajjaja. 

Pero ahora me lanza otro error **fatal error: uncaught error: cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in c:\mamp\htdocs\gourfood_02-08__modificado\public_html\templates\product-single.php:8**
En esta línea tengo `<h2 class="title"> <?php echo $i['item'] ?></h2>`

Yo estoy usando `$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);` pero tampoco me devuelve los datos con `mysqli_fetch_array`.
Qué desesperación

Comment: No es tan grave @SilviaPena, así que no te desesperes. Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. Aquí el problema era que te salía el error `i101`, si ya no te sale, sugiero que demos esta pregunta por cerrada, marcando como solución la respuesta que te ha ayudado a resolver _este_ problema. Luego, planteas otra pregunta con el nuevo problema, mostrando el código problemático, donde está `echo $i['item']`. Haciéndolo así, tendrás una respuesta más eficaz y certera. Pues aquí no se puede adivinar lo que significa `$i`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es comprobar los 5 diferentes de esta manera

1. Haces un array de los tipos (eid, hid, pid, poid y bid)
2. Compruebas con filter_input cada tipo
3. En caso de que exista detenemos el foreach con break, $id será igual al valor, en caso contrario FALSE o NULL (no estoy seguro)

   ```
   $categorias_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cid');
   $types = array("eid", "hid", "pid", "poid", "bid");

   foreach ($types as $value) {
     if($id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $value)) {
       break;
     }
   }

   if(!$id){
       $gf_query['message_code'] = 'i101';
       return false;
   }
   ```

PD: Lo he hecho sin probar el código

Comment: lo miro y te comento, gracias.

Comment: he utilizado lo que has recomendado con alguna modificación.
Si le paso por cadena GET {?poid=44} a modo de comprobación, me salta el mensaje de error "i101", es decir, que no recibe la id.
Sin embargo, he hecho un echo del foreach y si me sale el valor del array

Comment: Si es mediante GET supongo en vez de INPUT_POST debería ser INPUT_GET

Comment: $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $value)

Comment: no, lógicamente lo cambié por INPUT_GET. No se que puede estar mal

Comment: he estado mirando en phpMyAdmin y con la consulta que hago me devuelve tanto la id del item como la id de la categoría. Podría esto estar interfiriendo a la hora de intentar obtener la id del item cuando lo paso por GET o no tiene nada que ver?

Comment: ¿Podrías pasar un ejemplo del formato exacto que recibes?